# NodeJS - Ordering request and response

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, caching, sequence

In the following snippet, `client` is a pub/sub messaging client.

`comm.js` *(Obfuscated for obvious reasons....)*

```js
const communicator = class extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(options) {
        super();
        // Some configuration 
        // Then, instantiate
        this.commClient = ...
    }
    //
    sendMessage(message) {
        // Send message over TCP socket
    }
    //
    messageReceived() {
        // Receive message 
        this.commClient.on('message', (data) => {
            this.emit('msg', data)
        })
    }
}
```

```js
const comm = require('./comm.js')
let client = new comm.communicator()

const server = serverApp.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server up.')
})

serverApp.get('/book/:bookId', (req, res) => {
    client.sendMessage(JSON.stringify({
        action: 'get',
        message: req.params.bookId
    }))
    client.on('msg', (data) => {
        res.status(200).send(data)
    })
})
```

Consider the following sequence.

1. `GET` request received.
2. `client.sendMessage` done.
3. `client.on` *not* received yet.
4. Second `GET` request received.
5. `client.sendMessage` done.
6. `client.on` received.

How do I know for which invocation (first or second) was `client.on` received? Even if I kept track of it (with say, Redis), how do I know I am doing a `res.status(200).send` for the first or second invocation?

Comment: What kind of thing is `client` anyway?

Comment: At the moment, it is no more than `process.emit()` and `process.on()`.

Comment: No, I want to see how the variable `client` is defined. Your code never shows that.

Comment: Why is that important? (I will update the question, in the meantime, with the definition of `client`.)

Comment: Because to say anything about code that does not work it's necessary to know what the things in the code are. Examples need to be well-defined and complete unless you want people to guess.

Comment: And don't say "e.g. Kafka". Is it Kafka? Which version? You are asking a question about how to wire up API properly, and that requires knowing exactly what library you are talking about, if nothing else than to link to relevant documentation. This kind of thing should be self-evident when asking questions.

Comment: Calm down :) If you read the question closely, the key point is about sequencing the response correctly. The client is not the focus. Also, I am editing the question.